# Number not incrementing in PHP

Tags: php

I'm trying to get a value from my DB and then incrementing that number.

My code:

```
public function updateStat($res, $id) {
    $field = ($res == 'useful') ? 'useful' : 'not_useful';

    $currStat = $this->_db->query("SELECT {$field} 
        FROM vragen WHERE id = {$id}");

    $currStat = ($field == 'useful') ? 
        $currStat->first()->useful : 
        $currStat->first()->not_useful;

    $currStat++;

    die($currStat);

    $data = $this->_db->query("UPDATE vragen 
        SET {$field} = {$currStat} WHERE id = {$id}");
}
```

There's no output when dying this.

Comment: Try `die(var_dump($currStat))`, I have a suspicion you'll see "false", it's not an integer.

Comment: @Eihwaz the result is: `int(1)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just fixed the issue. Apparently dying it won't work, but the value is updated successfully in the DB.

Thanks everyone for your help!

Answer (score 0):

You can improve and simplify your code. Just replace select + update to only update:

```
public function updateStat($res, $id) {
    $data = $this->_db->query("UPDATE vragen SET {$field} = {$field} + 1 
        WHERE id = {$id}");
}
```

Comment: Are you select some value, then increment it, then update? If so you can use simple `UPDATE my_table SET my_column=my_column+1 WHERE id = my_id`.

Comment: I first need to know which field to update (`$field`) and then update it with the original value of the field (`$currStat`) incremented by 1

Comment: can you `var_dump($currStat)` just after string with `$this->_db->query(` ? and add comment with this output

Answer (score 0):

you got the same variable

**$currStat** = ($field == 'useful') ? $currStat->first()->useful : $currStat->first()->not_useful;

and

**$currStat**++;

could be always one.

Comment: Tried changing the variable names, still the same output

Comment: please echo $currStat before **$currStat++;**    problem in **$currStat = ($field == 'useful') ? 
        $currStat->first()->useful : 
        $currStat->first()->not_useful;**